# Weird redirection error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery datepicker. I wrote a function that would add a URL parameter (the date) when a user clicks a date. If the date is set, I would like to use the `setDate` method of the datepicker to set the date to the URL parameter. If it is not set, today's date will be used. I have accomplished getting the date from the URL, but the datepicker's date does not get set. And what's weird is that if I just manually add the `?date=xxxxx` to the url, it works perfectly. So it is occurring when I try to cause the redirection with `onSelect`

Page can be viewed [here](https://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/asp/Calendar/matt_test.asp).

[This page](https://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/asp/Calendar/matt_test2.asp) can be viewed to see that adding the parameter manually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the redirection. It has to do with the order of events you have on your page. On the page that doesn't work, you have your `.datepicker` initialization inside of `$(function () {})`, which means it will run when the DOM is ready (AFTER the rest of your Javascript). That's just binding an event. Then, immediately after binding the event, you attempt to call `.datepicker("setDate",qs_date)`. But you can't do that because your datepicker hasn't been initialized because the function in `$(function() {})` hasn't been executed yet. You should use this code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date, picker){ 
            var url = "http://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/asp/Calendar/matt_test.asp?date=" + date;
            window.location = url;
        }
    });

    var qs_date = location.href.match(/[?&]date=([^&#]+)/); 

    if (qs_date){
        qs_date = qs_date[1];
        alert(qs_date);
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",qs_date);
    }
});
```

In the working example, you don't use the `$(function () {})`, so the datepicker is immediately initalized, and then you set the date based on the querystring. The code above effectively does the same thing, except that it could technically be placed anywhere on the page. Inline Javascript that manipulates the DOM needs to be run after it has been rendered. That's why the working example works, and that's what `$(function () {})` guarantees too.

I'm sure there's a better method of initially setting the date on the datepicker, via it's initialization options, but what I provided should do the same thing, just be a little unnecessary.

**UPDATE:**

I *think* the `defaultDate` option allows you to set the initial date in the initialization - http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

So you could use:

```
$(function() {
    var qs_date = location.href.match(/[?&]date=([^&#]+)/);
    if (qs_date) {
        qs_date = qs_date[1];
        //alert(qs_date);
    }

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        defaultDate: qs_date,
        onSelect: function(date, picker){ 
            var url = "http://wwwdev.cco.purdue.edu/asp/Calendar/matt_test.asp?date=" + date;
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
});
```

It should work perfect because if `qs_date` is `null` (there's no match in the querystring), then setting the `defaultDate` value as `null` is the same as omitting it (its default value) and sets the date as today. So only if there's a match in the querystring will the default date be changed from today.

Comment: Perfect! I'm fairly new to js and jQuery so I did not know that the function wouldn't be called until after the page was set up. Thanks again!

Comment: @MattAltepeter No problem! Yeah, the `$(function () {});` is the same as `$(document).ready(function () {});`, which means "run the code inside this function passed to me as soon as the page is ready"...and by "page is ready", that basically means after the browser reaches rendering `</body>`. Anyways, I updated the answer to hopefully do what you're looking for, in a better way possibly